# Python bold multiline comments in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am using multiline comments for my function like such:

```py
def my_fn():
    """
    blah blah... source tags blah
    blah ...
    """
    ...
```

I am using VS Code and am referring to the comments displayed in the tooltip when hovering the mouse over a function.
I noticed that it picks up `code` format with tildes (`) but it doesn't show **bold** text when I use the double asterisks (*).
[image: screenshot showing what I mean]

**How can I bold/italicise some parts of my comment?**

Not sure if it is a Python thing or a VS Code thing.

Comment: It's a VS Code thing. As far as Python is concerned,  a comment (and code generally) doesn't have formatting. And I don't know of any programming language that does.

Comment: Add a screenshot of that's happening to help people understand better.

Comment: @cryanbhu -Which VSCode extensions did you use?

Comment: @BoarGules Java does have. You can use some html tags in function/method comments. E.g <code> <br/> etc

Answer (score 1):

1.In VSCode, we can add the following styles for setting all comments in the file "`settings.json`":

> ```
> "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
>     "comments": {
>       "fontStyle": "italic", // "bold" or "italic" or "underline" 
>       "foreground": "#aaaaaa",
>     }
>   }
> ```

[image]

[image]

2.For changing the style of part of the comment, you could search for related extensions in VSCode, they will provide different styles, for example: extension `Better-Comments`.